# R read.csv as numeric or string

Tags: r, excel, csv, read.csv

I have a somewhat general question about how `read.csv(...)` works.

When I read csv datasets (created and exported from Excel), some columns are read into R as numeric (correctly), while others end up as either character (`stringsAsFactor=FALSE`) or factors (`stringsAsFactor=TRUE`). How does R determine if its string or numeric in the import process? There is no discernible difference in the columns - e.g., two columns, both t scores, yet one was read in as character, the other as numeric. Can someone explain this to me? (Does my question even make sense?)

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: Can you show a couple of rows of actual data from your CSV file?

Comment: One of the columns almost certainly contains text somewhere. "Missing" or "#!" or something

Comment: There are a million possible reasons. It's silly to guess. Provide a small [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of a file you are having trouble with and we can tell you for sure.

Comment: The function that makes the decision is `type.convert()` which is just a helper function for `read.table()` which does most of the `read.csv()` work. Effectively it "attempts to convert it to logical, integer, numeric or complex, and failing that converts it to factor unless `as.is = TRUE`" Look at the documentation or source code for the specifics.